# Too many columns in html table, print the remaining columns "next line"

Tags: php, html, for-loop, html-table

[image]
What I am trying to achieve is to make a table that looks like a "road" and each TD (column) represents 100 m of the road (each td has data/value). The length of the road/table depends on the LENGTH entered by the user in the database. The road may be very long so I want to break it at some point (through loop maybe? ) and continue printing on the screen until the desired length is achieved.

```
<table>
.
.
.
// $num is value from the database
for($i=1;$i<=$num;$i++)
{
  echo '<td>some data</td>';
}
```

Is there a way to break the table and print the remaining columns "next line" ?

Comment: maybe use '/n' before </td>?

Comment: he? what do you mean exactly? Describe your problem a little bit better and give us some sample of the desired output. in general, to *split* columns to many rows is using `<tr>` tag, however not sure if you're asking for that?

Comment: Optionally you can use CSS to make sure that the table has always the width of the parent element.

Comment: @Psycho - A new line is with a back slash `\n` (or `\r\n` etc depending on the OS). But I believe the OP is talking about the view in the browser, where new lines aren't rendered either way.

Comment: Please show us a screen dump of how it looks now and do a mock of how you want it.  You should also include what you've tried yourself to solve it, since the posted code is very basic and doesn't tell us anything really. Your description isn't clear either.

Comment: @Psycho in HTML `<br>` would be better option for line break, but somehow I feel it's still not about breaking lines.

Comment: For example you have 8 columns and you want to show 5 columns on first, the remaining 3 columns in next line? like `<tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td><td>Column 4</td><td>Column 5</td></tr>` `<tr><td>Column 6</td><td>Column 7</td><td>Column 9</td></tr>`. Right?

Comment: Thanks for your responses, I've edited my problem and explained it in more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox to move remaining columns to next line

```
    table tr{
        display: flex;
        flex-flow:row wrap;
    }
```